# Convolution product and zero-product property

Tags: convolution

The convolution product for continuous integrable functions on $[0,+\infty)$ is defined as
$$
(f * g)(t) = \int_0^t f(s) g(t-s) ds.
$$
Does it has a zero-product property?
The paper [Variational principles for linear elastodynamics](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00248489) by M. Gurtin in eq. $(2.7)$ says
$$
\text{(b)} \quad \vartheta * \omega = 0 \quad \text{implies either } \vartheta = 0 \text{ or } \omega = 0;
$$
but the book that he references in the footnote ([J. Mikusinski - Operational Calculus - 1959](https://archive.org/details/operationalcalcu0000miku/page/n509/mode/2up)) does not report such a property.

Somebody able to prove or provide a counterexample?

Comment: Have you tried to prove (b) ?

Comment: @KurtG. yes I tried supposing that $f(t) > 0$ in $[0,\tau]$ and reasoning on the inequality $0<m\leq f(t) \leq M$ and integrating, but I realized there was a flaw in my proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $f,g$ are continuous functions defined on $[0,+\infty)$ and $\mathcal{L}$-transformable, then
$$
f * g = 0 \qquad \implies \qquad f = 0 \lor g = 0
$$
**Proof**:
Set $F = \mathcal{L}[f], G = \mathcal{L}[g]$, then
$$
\mathcal{L}[f * g] = F \cdot G = 0,
$$
If exists $s_0$ such that $F(s_0) \neq 0$ then exists $\delta>0$ such that $F(s) \neq 0 \; \forall s:|s-s_0|<\delta$, of consequence $G(s)=0 \; \forall s:|s-s_0|<\delta$, but being a holomorphic function $G = 0$.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest proof is probably to use the convolution theorem for the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems):
For all $s>0$,

\begin{align}
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-st}(f*g)(t)\,dt=\Big(\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-st}f(t)\,dt\Big)\Big(\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-st}g(t)\,dt\Big)\,.
\end{align}
When $f,g\ge 0$ and $(f*g)\equiv 0$ then (since $f,g$ are both continuous) we
must have either $f\equiv 0$ or $g\equiv 0$.

Comment: If $F,G$ are the two Laplace transform, $F(s)G(s)=0$ is valid pointwise, but does not mean that one of the two vanish identically, I think

Comment: $F$ is an integral over a nonnegative function $f$. When $F(s)$ is zero for a single $s$ that means the continuous function $f$ has to vanish identically. Likewise this holds for $G$.

Comment: OK, true, but the hypothesis $f,g>0$ is too strong, and not in my initial question.

Comment: Correct. This indicates what counter examples one should look for.

Comment: @enzotib . [Here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~marshall/math_135/UniqueLaplace.pdf) is a proof that shows the result without the assumption $f,g\ge 0$ as long as $f,g$ are piecewise continuous. That's the case in your question. Please dive into this. I don't have time for everything.